# How to retrieve image from server vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to retrieve image from server in vuejs and display to blade laravel,
      the problem is not display image the below code.

```
<tr v-for="post in posts">
    <td>{{post.title}}</td>
    <td>{{post.content}}</td>
    <td><img :src="'storage/image' + post.image"/></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deletePost(post)"><i style="color:white" class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that storage is accessible to begin with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then your image url is wrong:

```
<td><img :src="`/storage/image/${post.image}`"/></td>
```